# What is the distribution of the ratio of two t-distributed random variables?

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, density-function, t-distribution

x is t-distributed;
y is t-distributed.

How is x/y distributed?

Does it have a closed-form formula?

Comment: Are these standard $t$, or location-scale family $t$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, your question has been answered in the affirmative in the following 1969 JASA paper. You can find there the formulas for the pdf and cdf of $W=X/Y$ with $X$ and $Y$ following a t-distribution.

> S. James Press, "The t-Ratio Distribution", 1969, Journal of the
>   American Statistical Association, Vol. 64, No. 325, pp. 242-252.